# MongoDB Python Codio Add a new document to the collection

Tags: python, mongodb, codio

So I'm supposed to use Codio to create a Python file that creates a new document to the existing MongoDB collection called 'inspections' in the database 'city'
But it's not successfully adding the new document to the collection.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giwwb.jpg)

```
import json
from bson import json_util
from pymongo import MongoClient

connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection['city']
collection = db['inspections']

def insert_document(document):
    try:
        result=collection.save(document)
    except ValidationError as ve:
        abort(400, str(ve))
return result

def main():
    print "Hi"
    myDocument = { "id" : "0203-2019-ssp1",
               "certificate_number" : 5382334,
               "business_name" : "BUILDING TO SERVE INC.",
               "date" : "Jul 22 2015",
               "result" : "Violation Issued",
               "sector" : "Home Improvement Contractor - 100",
               "address" : [ "city" : "JAMAICA", "zip" : 11432, "street" : 
               "HILLSIDE AVE", "number" : 17939 ] }

    print insert_document(myDocument)

main()
```

This is how I ran the Create.py file in the Codio terminal.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzMlq.jpg)

After running the Create.py, I did db.inspections.find({"id":"0203-2019-ssp1"}) but it's not there.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJSzk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`pymongo.collection.Collection.save` is a deprecated method in version 3.0 and up of the pymongo library <sup>[1](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.save)</sup>

Ideally, you want to use the `pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one` <sup>[2](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one)</sup>

```
def insert_document(document):
    try:
        result=collection.insert_one(document)
    except ValidationError as ve:
        abort(400, str(ve))
    return result
```

Comment: I just tried that but it did not fix the problem. Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: I just rechecked your screenshot. While you correctly make `Create.py` executable, I don't see that it is run.